# Is it possible to add custom send button in outlook message form in outlook 2013 add in project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I just started working with outlook 2013 addin project template, and need to add new send button, under regular send button on message form (check the image).
Is it possible???

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. The Outlook object model (nor extensibility model) doesn't provide anything for that.

However, you are free to subclass Outlook Windows using Windows API functions. Take a look at the [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) page for more information. Also you may find the [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) sample project helpful.

Also you may consider using a commercial components to get the job done for you. See the [TopSubpane](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php#form-regions) layout which comes from ADX.